# How to retrieve jQuery.mynamespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

i have following code,i stored value in imgwidth variable

```
var newImg = new Image();
        newImg.src = document.getElementById('image').src;
        var height = newImg.height;
        var width = newImg.width;
            var width_img = width/3;
            jQuery.mynamespace = {imgwidth : width_img};
```

how can i retrieve imgwidth variable globally?

Answer (score 1):

You can say `jQuery.mynamespace.imgwidth`, because jQuery is available globally.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?:

```
function testa() {
   jQuery.test = {data: 1, data2: 2};
}

testa()

alert(jQuery.test.data  + "\n" + jQuery.test.data2);
​
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/RqDks/)